# Asking for opinions : One sequence for all tables

Tags: oracle, database-design

Here's another one I've been thinking about lately. 
We have concluded in earlier discussions : 'natural primary keys are bad, artificial primary keys are good.'
Working with Hibernate earlier I have seen that Hibernate default creates one sequence for all tables. At first I was puzzled by this, why would you do this. But later I saw the advantage that it makes linking parents and children fool proof. Because no tables have the same primary key value, accidentally linking a parent with a table that is not a child gives no results.

Does anyone see any downsides to this approach. I only see one : you cannot have more than 999999999999999999999999999 records in your database.

Comment: "We have concluded in earlier discussions"--internal discussion or something on SO?

Comment: Several discussions on SO. And 'we' means 'me' ;-)

Comment: Natural keys are not "bad". They are essential from a data integrity perspective. They allow users to identify the real world things being identified in the database. In principle a sequence could be a natural key too. Actually I much prefer the term "business key" but it means the same as "natural key" - i.e. a key used to identify information outside the database (by business users for example).

Comment: @dportas - natural keys are useful, although it can be bad to use natural keys as primary keys / @@Id fields in your application, when your application is the system of record for those values and when those values might need to change later.   

I learned that the hard way many years ago, when I made username an @@Id column (well, no annotations back then).  That's a clear natural key - unique record identifier with business meaning.  Only problem is, what if you need to change it and there's 10 other tables using it as a foreign key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on how sequences are implemented in the database, always hitting the same sequence can be better or worse. When only a few or only one thread request new values, there will be no locking issues. But a bad implementation could cause congestion.

Another problem is rolling back transactions: Sequences don't get rolled back (because someone else might have requested a higher value already), so you can have large gaps which will eat your number space much more quickly than you might expect. OTOH, it will take some time to eat 2 or 4 billion IDs (if you "only" use 32 bit (signed) ints), so it's rarely an issue in practice.

Lastly, you can't easily reset the sequence if you have to. But if you need to have a restarting sequence (say, number of records since midnight), you can tell Hibernate to create/use a second sequence.

A major advantage is that you can uniquely identify objects anywhere in the DB just by the ID. That means you can severely cut down the log information you write in the production system and still find something if you only have the ID.

Comment: Ref: "2 or 4 billion IDs (if you use 32 bit (signed) ints)", the maximum value for an Oracle sequence is actually 10^27, and an Oracle NUMBER type will store integers up to 38 digits of precision. Should keep us going for a while.

Comment: I means "even if you only used 32bit ints" for an ID. Most people today will use 64bit (LONG or BIGNUM) or more or even UUIDs.

Comment: Indeed. My comment was really to point out that Oracle number data types are rather different to other systems. Reference docs here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222

Comment: Running out of numbers shouldn't be an issue if you use NUMBER.  Running at a trillion transactions/sec, you are good for 31.6 million millenia.

Answer (score 11):

There could be performance issues with all code getting values from a single sequence - see [this Ask Tom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:451611870226342::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2985886242221).

Comment: In our case when we increased the cache of seqeunces significantly the performance of single sequence and multiple sequence was similar .

Comment: Ahh you might also want to scroll down on that thread and look at Mr Mark Bobaks reply it mirrors my experiences

Comment: @Edwards thanks for pointing that nugget out, very interesting indeed.

Comment: "The maximum value for an Oracle sequence is actually 10^27" -- you could theoretically make a couple sequences and stagger the start values appropriately. Be sure to set up a script that will notify the admin in case your app lives for a very, very long time.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer having one sequence per table. This comes from one general observation: Some tables ("master tables") have a relatively small row count and have to be kept "forever". For example, the customer table in an ERP.

In other tables ("transaction tables"), many rows are generated perpetually, but after some time, those rows can be archived (or simply deleted). The most extreme example is a tracing table used for debugging purposes; it might grow by hundreds of rows per second, but each row is obsolete after a few days.

Small IDs in the master tables make it easier when working directly on the database, e.g. for debugging purposes.

```
select * from orders where customerid=415
```

vs

```
select * from orders where customerid=89461836571
```

But this is only a minor issue. The bigger issue is cycling. If you use one sequence for all tables, you simply cannot let it restart. With one sequence per table, you can restart the sequences for the transaction tables when you have archived or deleted the old data. Master tables hardly ever have that problem, since they grow much slower.

I see little value in having only one sequence for all tables. The arguments told so far do not convince me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of disadvantages of using a single sequence:-

- reduced concurrency. Handing out the next sequence value involves synchronisation.  In practice, I do not think this is likely to be a big problem
- Oracle has special code when maintaining btree indexes to detect monotonically increasing values and balance the tree approriately
- The CBO might have a better time estimating range queries on the index (if you ever did this) if most values were filled in

An advantage might be that you can determine the order of inserts amongst different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there are pros and cons to the one-sequence versus one-sequence-per-table approach.  Personally I find the ability to assign a truly unique identifier to a row, making each id column a uuid, to be enough of a benefit to outweigh any disadvantages.  As Aaron D. succinctly writes:

> you can uniquely identify objects anywhere in the DB just by the ID

And, for most applications, due to the way Hibernate3 batches IMPORT statements, this will not be a performance bottleneck unless massive amounts of records are vying for the same db resource (SELECT hibernate_sequence.nextval FROM dual).

Also, this sequence mapping is not supported in the latest release (1.2) of Grails.  Though it was supported in Grails 1.1 (!).  It now requires subclassing one of the Hibernate dialect classes as a workaround.

For those using Grails/GORM, have a look at this JIRA entry:

[Oracle Sequence mappings ignored](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5783)

Comment: Workaround (and Java code) are summarized here --> 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564491/does-overloading-grails-static-mapping-property-to-bolt-on-database-objects-vio