# Does overloading Grails static 'mapping' property to bolt on database objects violate DRY?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

Does Grails static 'mapping' property in Domain classes violate DRY?
Let's take a look at the canonical domain class:

> class Book {
>          Long id
>          String title
>          String isbn
>          Date published
>          Author author
>          static mapping = {
>               id generator:'hilo', params:[table:'hi_value',column:'next_value',max_lo:100]
>          }
>   }

or:

> class Book {  ...
>  
>           static mapping = {
>               id( generator:'sequence', params:[sequence_name: "book_seq"] )
>       }
>   }

And let us say, continuing this thought, that I have my Grails application working with HSQLDB or MySQL, but the IT department says I must use a commercial software package (written by a large corp in Redwood Shores, Calif.).

Does this change make my web application nobbled in development and test environments?  MySQL supports autoincrement on a primary key column but does support sequence objects, for example.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this sort of 'only when in production mode' without loading up the domain class?

Answer (score 1):

This question (re: sequences) is more related to Hibernate than Grails -- and is well documented on [our site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536479/asking-for-opinions-one-sequence-for-all-tables)

There are typically several reasons that the 'IT department says I must use a commercial software package'....  Among these are naming standards for database objects such as views, tables, even columns.

Another reason would be a standard such as 'every table must have its own sequence' that is a common (oft over-used) practice to assure ids for objects fall in certain ranges.
To accomplish this you could add a static mapping block for the renames, e.g. COMMENT becomes COMMENT_TBL  and subclass the Hibernate Dialect for the database you are using.

---

N.B.: ORACLE-specific id generator in mapping closure are now ignored by the Grails 1.2.x framework, so this question is not relevant to recent versions.  See [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5783)
for some background on this question -  and orig recommendation [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3138).  Keep in mind if you just wanted the one-sequence-per-table approach you could only use the subclass Oracle10gDialect  as recommended by the hibernate [community](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Customsequences) , specifically Rob Hasselbaum:

```
public class TableNameSequenceGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

/**
 * If the parameters do not contain a {@link SequenceGenerator#SEQUENCE} name, we
 * assign one based on the table name.
 */
public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {
    if(params.getProperty(SEQUENCE) == null || params.getProperty(SEQUENCE).length() == 0) {
        String tableName = params.getProperty(PersistentIdentifierGenerator.TABLE);
        if(tableName != null) {
            String seqName = “seq_” + tableName;
            params.setProperty(SEQUENCE, seqName);               
        }
    }
    super.configure(type, params, dialect);
}
```

}

```
public class MyDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
   public Class getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
      return TableNameSequenceGenerator.class;
   }
}
```