# Which is better: single global sequence vs. sequence per table?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

In a JPA/Hibernate application using native Oracle sequences, is it better to use a single global sequence like `hibernate_sequence`, or to define a separate sequence per table?

It seems like a single sequence is easier to maintain, but could make troubleshooting or ad hoc queries harder by making longer ID's.

Comment: Do you understand how big a Java long is? Not a lot of apps have to fear running out of ids using a long, even if they used a single sequence for all objects and ran for 100 years.

Comment: Some more discussion about this issue here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536479/asking-for-opinions-one-sequence-for-all-tables)

Comment: Yes, I just did the math and realized that the concern of overflowing a 64-bit long is unrealistic.

I did think of another good reason to use individual sequences, though: if the table contents get separated from their sequence somehow, you can re-generate the max value much more easily from a single table.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although cacheing alleviates it, a sequence can cause contention when multiple sessions require nextvals.
If you have one sequence serving all tables then all inserts on all tables will contend for the same sequence. If you are after performance, one sequence for each table will give less contention.

Comment: Good point- accepting this answer, as contention is the one thing I hadn't thought of already, although concurrent inserts are not likely to be a factor for me personally.  The other issues - clarity and convenience of low #'s for troubleshooting, vs. more Oracle objects to maintain, seem to be mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: you may be interested in this thread: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:451611870226342::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2985886242221

Answer (score 4):

A single sequence means no matching ids in two tables. In practice I like this because you can never get something when you accidentally query the wrong table. Particularly useful with deletes. It is a little thing but I find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use a sequence per table.  It is just a little cleaner in my book.  The standard at my current placement of employment is sequence per table.